# iterm2 problems with a tringle symbol in the .zshrc pront

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I have installed too many times and configure the .p10k.zsh file too many times as well !!!, but always appear a triangle at begins of the terminal, how to avoid that triangle in blue color ??

Thanks

[image]